# How to send notification when new public project was successfully created in GitLab?

Tags: email, configuration, notifications, gitlab, devops

Some of my admins want to know when public repo is created in GtLab. How to turn email notification for that in gitlab ?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out this, I just used file hooks:

```
return unless ARGS['event_name'] == 'project_create' && ARGS['project_visibility'] == 'public'
```